# Ubuntu 18.04 - Where is .bashrc?

Tags: upgrade, bashrc, 18.04

I checked by `ls -al` in my home directory but I don't see .bashrc file in my home directory. Ubuntu 18.04 release notes does not mention anything about this. I installed it without formatting previous /home partition after deleting files like .bash_, .local, .gnome, etc. I am able to use the pc like normal but where is the bashrc file now? Isn't it supposed to be recreated automatically?

Comment: On my clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS `~/.bashrc` is in place. On both Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME) and MATE. You did something wrong.

Comment: I think I have mentioned it is not a clean install on purpose. Please ask for clarification before downvoting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Isn't it supposed to be recreated automatically?

No. A default `.bashrc` file is copied from `/etc/skel` when a user account is first created by `adduser` - if you retained your previous user account(s) then there would be no reason for it to be re-created.

You can copy it manually from `/etc/skel` yourself.

See `man adduser`.

Comment: Oh! I created a new user with exact same username as previous install to preserve all data.

Comment: @sziraqui but you re-used the home directory, yes?

Comment: Yes. I purposely created separate root and home partitions when I first installed 17.10 a year ago as I planned to switch to 18.04 LTS. I keep all my development tools (around 64 gb right now) in home partition to prevent re-setup on critical upgrades. I expected GUI will run adduser while installation (it did) but providing identical username seems to have caused problem.